# What is the difference between cypress.json and cypress.config.js?

Tags: cypress

What is the difference between the files `cypress.json` and `cypress.config.js` configuration files in Cypress?

Comment: Did you just ask a question so you could answer it yourself? The timestamp between your question and answer are literally within the same second.

Comment: @DJSDev Yes, I didn’t find it anywhere until I checked the docs (took awhile ). It is allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cypress configuration doc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration), `cypress.config.js` is used is Cypress version **10 and higher** and `cypress.json` is used in earlier versions.